# nodejs, jsPDF e Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, jspdf

não estou conseguindo instalar o jsPDF no meu nodejs com npm. Rodei `npm install node-jspdf` para trabalhar com nodejs, mas não instala porque dá problema ao rodar o arquivo `install.sh`. Mesmo especificando a versão do pacote dá problema. Então eu baixei o zip do node-jspdf (indicado no arquivo `install.sh`), descompactei e criei as pastas necessárias, indicadas no mesmo arquivo de instalação. Ao executar o app o módulo não é localizado. Porém eu consegui gerar um PDF fazendo referência ao módulo diretamente, mas não sei se isso dá certo para usar depois:

ASSIM A APP FUNCIONOU EM PRINCÍPIO:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = './jsPDF/';
jsPDF = require(path + 'jspdf');

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10);
fs.writeFile('teste.pdf', doc.output());
```

O PDF é criado corretamente na pasta local. Mas pretendo fazer com que ele seja enviado para o browser. Porém se eu usar o exemplo do Githud, da forma abaixo, aparece o erro "navigator is not defined":

ASSIM A APP DEU ERRO

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = './jsPDF/';
jsPDF = require(path + 'jspdf');

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10);

doc.save('Test.pdf', function(err){console.log('saved!');});  // <<<<<<==== Gera o erro
```

Perguntas:
1) Posso usar o jspdf indicando o path do módulo diretamente e salvando o arquivo da forma que funcionou?
2) Esse erro "navigator is not defined" não seria porque estou apenas executando um script? Imagino que se executar via browser vai parar o problema...

Comment: você tem a versão mais atualizada do node? parece que não. digita `node -v` e fala qual é a versão

Comment: Npm: '4.4.4', node: '6.10.2'

Comment: tentou instalando o `node-jspdf`? `navigator` é uma variável do navegador

Comment: sim, fiz como você indicou `npm install node-jspdf --save`. Aí dá erro no arquivo `install.sh`, mas eu o abri e fiz na mão o que precisava. Então criei o arquivo com o código padrão do "hello word", tal como está indicado no página do node-jspdf, mas dá esse erro. Então executei o código conforme indiquei lá em cima (o que funcionou), com essa ressalva de ter que indicar o path relativo, ficando então as duas dúvidas pendentes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas para registro: consegui fazer funcionar a geração do PDF, mas não via instalação normal com `npm install`. Fiz o seguinte: 
1) Baixei o arquivo ZIP master do jsPDF no Github, nos Releases a versão compatível com minha versão do NodeJS, pois não estou usando a mais atual (não vem ao caso o motivo); 
2) Descompactei o arquivo e coloquei direto na pasta `node_modules` do meu projeto; 
3) No código apontei o pacote diretamente no path relativo: `require('./meu_path_relativo/node_modules/pasta_jsPDF/jspdf')`;

Sei que não é a estratégia correta, mas foi a única forma de fazer funcionar em minha instalação no Windows.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a documentação, o `jsPDF` é um package `client-side`. 
Como você está trabalhando com `node`, então o package que eles recomendam é o `node-jspdf`.
Para isso, recomendo desinstalar seu `jspdf` e instalar `node-jspdf` através de:

```
npm unistall jspdf --save
npm install node-jspdf --save
```

Espero que agora funcione, abraços!

Comment: Guilherme, mas o jsPDF já existe há bastante tempo e imagino que deveria ser compatível com essa minha versão, não? Além disso, se ele só funcionasse na versão mais atualizada do Node, imagino que haveria muita gente reclamando também, mas não consegui encontrar reclamações deste tipo. Outra coisa: onde vou utilizar o que estou desenvolvendo, tem que ser um Node 4.2 se não me engano. E se o jsPDF não rodar nesta versão então nem adiantará para mim...

Comment: O comando `npm install <pkg>` instala a versão da última `tag` por default, fazendo todo sentido a última versão do pkg exigir a última versão do node. O que você pode fazer é instalar uma versão com uma `tag` mais antiga. o link das releases é https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases e para instalar use `npm install jspdf@1.2.61`, por exemplo.

Comment: Grande Guilherme! Parece que agora instalou sem problemas, mas ainda ficou com erro ao executar o exemplo mais simples do "Hello world" que está no próprio Github do jsPDF. Quando executo aquele exemplo com `var jsPDF = require('jspdf');` no início, aparece a mensagem: **ReferenceError: window is not defined**. Se eu usar `var jsPDF = require('node-jspdf');` como já vi em alguns exemplos, aparece o erro **Cannot find module 'node-jspdf'**.

Comment: essa variável `windows` é só pra aplicação client-side. eu nunca usei jspdf, mas de acordo com a documentação, o jspdf é clientside e o node-jspdf é server-side. como você quer pra node, então você deve instalar `node-jspdf`. vou editar minha resposta

Comment: Guilherme, consegui parcialmente resolver o problema, pois tive que indicar o path do módulo diretamente. Alterei minha pergunta também. Dê uma verificada quando puder por favor e obrigado novamente pela atenção.